# Automorphisms of finite groups $Z_n $ , $D_n $ and $S_n $.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any method to compute all the automorphisms of a finite group say $Z_6$, $D_8$ or $S_3$ ?

Comment: Are you asking for the question in the title, the question in the first half of the sentence or the question in the second half of the sentence?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli There is no question in the title.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Feel free not to see the issue.

Comment: I want to construct all the ismorphisms from $Z_6$ to $Z_6$.

Comment: We know all the automorphisms of **these** groups.

Comment: @Miller: Consider the automorphisms yielded by the maps $1\to1$ and $1\to 5$ from $\mathbb Z_6$ to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An automorphism of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ must map a generator, say $\bar 1$ to another generator of  $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. As these are the classes of the numbers in $\;\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ which are coprime to $n$ (i.e. the units in the *ring*  $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$), we have that
$$\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)\simeq(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times.$$
 In the precise case of $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$, this means $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z)$ is the cyclic group of order $2$.

As to $D_8$, it can be shown that the automorphism group of $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to a semi-direct product 
$$\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\rtimes\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)\simeq \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\rtimes(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$$
(see [Wikipedia: Dihedral Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Automorphism_group))

For the automorphisms of $S_n3$, the situation is more complex, see the dedicated page of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups).  The case of $S_3$ is this:
$$S_3\simeq\operatorname{Aut}(S_3).$$
Indeed an automorphism of $S_n$ is defined by the images of a set of generators of $S_n$. $S_3$ is is generated by a transposition $\tau$ and a $3$-cycle.  The transposition has  for image a transposition, which makes three choices, and the $3$-cycle has for image itself of the other  $3$-cycle (its inverse). In all, this makes three possibilities, so $\bigl|\operatorname{Aut}(S_3)\bigr|=6$.

Now the *inner automorphisms* are also six in number since they're isomorphic to $S_3$. So the automorphisms of $S_3$ are simply their inner automorphisms, whence  the isomorphism.